# how to link sub-document with reference file for auto-completion in vim-latex?

Tags: bibtex, vim

I am writing a long document so I am making use of sub-documents and inserting them with `\include`.

The problem I am facing is that as the `\bibliography{}` line is on the main .tex file the sub-documents  are not able to 'see' what is in the bibtex file, hence when I run the auto-completion function while editing the sub-document I cannot see the options for citing.

If I try the auto-completion function while editing the main.tex file I am able to see all the different options for citing.

How can I tell the sub-document to see that bibtex file too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I found the trick:

You just need to add the line

`%\bibliography{bibtexfile}`

as a comment and vim will know where to look for the auto-completion options